# How to set install options for remote software installation with powershell?

Tags: powershell, installation, anaconda, remote-desktop, start-process

I'm attempting to install anaconda (using the 'Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe' installer) on a large number of remote windows 10 PCs.  I've installed software remotely before, but always using the default options. With this install I specifically need to set it to add for all users and to add anaconda to the system path.
So my questions are:

1) In general, how do you specify options when installing through powershell

2) How to determine what the options are for a specific installer (in this case, Anaconda)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I'll leave the question up in case someones else has the same issue.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {powershell.exe C:\AnacondaInstall\Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe /S -Verb runAs /InstallationType=AllUsers /AddToPath=1 /RegisterPython=1}
```

The options I needed were available on the anaconda webpage:https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows.html#install-win-silent